# a difficult query code

Tags: mysql, drupal

```
  $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(t.nid), n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} t ON n.nid = t.nid WHERE n.nid != %d AND (';

// except the current node
$args = array($node->nid);
  $tids = array();

  foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
 $tids[] = 't.tid = %d';
  $args[] = $term->tid;
 }

$query .= implode(' OR ', $tids) .  ')';
```

the query code is written by a guru. but i don't understand the rest AND (';...part.hope someone can explain it for me. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the finished generated query (`echo $query;`) and it will become clearer.

Comment: how we know that in foreach "$node->taxonomy" is an array? and when i loop,
foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
}
the output that i get will be the $term's value. i don't know how it is change into the 't.tid = %d' and $term->tid. thank you.

Comment: @runeveryday I think "taxonomy" is a predefined object. The `%d` replacement comes from `drupal_query()`. Does that answer your question?